# New object validation - DataTable to List<RelGeral>

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

Unfortunately I'm stopped at this point...

I have all my data on my DataTable and now I need to cast to a List and return, but first I need to validate my data. I need to validate if decimal, int and etc aren't null and I can parse them properly.

What you guys suggest?

```
return (from DataRow rw in dt.Rows
        select new RelGeral
        {
            SR = rw["SR"].ToString(),
            UF = rw["UF"].ToString(),
            AndamentoQnt = (int)rw["AndamentoQnt"],
            AndamentoVl = (decimal)rw["AndamentoVl"],
            BenEncQnt = (int)rw["BenEncQnt"],
            DspRemissaoQnt = (int)rw["DspRemissaoQnt"],
            DspRemissaoVl = (decimal)rw["DspRemissaoVl"],
            Estado = rw["Estado"].ToString(),
            FinalizadaQnt = (int)rw["FinalizadaQnt"],
            FinalizadaVl = (decimal)rw["FinalizadaVl"],
            RemitidosQnt = (int)rw["RemitidosQnt"],
            RemitidosVl = (decimal)rw["RemitidosVl"],
            TotalQnt = (int)rw["TotalQnt"],
            TotalVl = (decimal)rw["TotalVl"]
        }).ToList();
```

Comment: Did you mean "stopped" (instead of "stocked")?

Comment: If you are just looking to check if your row column is null I think you can just compare it to DBNull.Value so something like this with a ternary if statement might work ,  AndamentoQnt  = (rw["AndamentoQnt"] == DBNull.Value) ? 0 : (int)rw["AndamentoQnt"];  or you need to make your properties of your class nullable and check on them before trying to display them.

Comment: @Bearcat9425, yeah you're right! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was "stopped", so simple :/
...

```
  return (from DataRow rw in dt.Rows
        select new RelGeral
        {
           TotalQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["TotalQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["TotalQnt"].ToString()),
           AndamentoQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["AndamentoQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["AndamentoQnt"].ToString()),
           BenEncQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["BenEncQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["BenEncQnt"].ToString()),
           DspRemissaoQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["DspRemissaoQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["DspRemissaoQnt"].ToString()),
           FinalizadaQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["FinalizadaQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["FinalizadaQnt"].ToString()),
           RemitidosQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["RemitidosQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["RemitidosQnt"].ToString()),
           SR = rw["SR"].ToString(),
           UF = rw["UF"].ToString(),
           Estado = rw["Estado"].ToString(),
           AndamentoVl = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["AndamentoVl"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["AndamentoVl"].ToString()),
           DspRemissaoVl = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["DspRemissaoVl"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["DspRemissaoVl"].ToString()),
           FinalizadaVl = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["FinalizadaVl"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["FinalizadaVl"].ToString()),
           RemitidosVl = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["RemitidosVl"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["RemitidosVl"].ToString()),
           TotalVl = decimal.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["TotalVl"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["TotalVl"].ToString()),
           SR_COD = rw["SR_COD"].ToString()
        }).OrderBy(c => c.SR_COD).ToList();
```

Can this be improved in some way?

Comment: If you want this side to be cleaner you can simply make your properties nullable with the ? operator in your class like public int? TotalQt, but ultimately you are going to have to perform null checking somewhere.  Doing that you would have to perform null checking at your gui level before you display information which in my humble opinion I would prefer what you have.  Either that or make your values in the database not nullable which if its an established application would be very difficult.

Comment: What you mean by saying `Can this be improved some way`? Note that `ToString()` method after `rw["FieldName"]` is redundant! If you project DataRow to specific class, you can improve this class by adding necessary validation.

Answer (score 0):

The content above is enlightening and caused me to consider the software I support and investigate further, and I found that:

The solution is okay when the values are "DBNULL" but in the general case where an entity could be "NULL" instead of "DBNULL", an exception would be raised by the  expression rw["TotalQnt"].ToString() in the line

TotalQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty(rw["TotalQnt"].ToString()) ? "0" : rw["TotalQnt"].ToString()),

when rw["TotalQnt"] is "null".

For a more general case of supporting "NULL" or "DBNULL" or a numeric string, using an interpolated string expression would solve the problem and change the line to

TotalQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrEmpty($"{rw["TotalQnt"]}") ? "0" : rw["TotalQnt"].ToString()),

And taking this filtering a step further to handle whitespace for an even more general case:

TotalQnt = int.Parse(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace($"{rw["TotalQnt"]}") ? "0" : rw["TotalQnt"].ToString()),